# Cannot GET /string/string ( A problem with router adress in Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-handlebars

[image: Here is exactly how error looks like]

I am using express-handlebars for my routers. I have a navbar in my project website and after i get in addpost site and if i press another link, page will get error which is like Cannot Get /blabla/blabla

I realize that, all routes are one word like;/blog/contact etc...

But Add Post route is like /post/new.

And here is my mainrouter.js code

```
router.get("/contact" , (req,res) => {
    res.render("./site/contact")
})
router.get("/login" , (req,res) => {
    res.render("../views/site/login")
})
router.get("/register" , (req,res) => {
    res.render("./site/register")
})
router.get("/posts/new" , (req,res) => {
    res.render("./site/addpost")
})
```

and my navbar code,,

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="about">About</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="blog">Blog</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="posts/new">Add Post</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="contact">Contact</a>
</li>
```

edit: I solve the general problem. Now the problem is, i get this error only when i press the add post button

Comment: You don't have a route handler for `/posts/contact`. Why are you trying to load this URL?

Comment: @jabaa Yes, I solved it like i add "/" for every route in navbar in the beginning. 
edit: and i wasn't trying this URL, it was just auto doing it. All solved now. Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Do you still have a question?

Comment: @jabaa Yes alright i solved all now. I forgot for HTML of addbutton, instead of posts/test, i wrote post/test. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Change all the `href` values to be absolute paths, so they all start with `/` such as `href="/about"` and `href="/contact"`.  Then, the href won't be relative to the current path's page and will work uniformly, even when in a page that is not at the top level.  Without that, the browser takes the path of the current page and appends it to the href value which is not what you want.